# Where can I find more about the conceptual approach to linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Till very recent, I only knew about the computational approach to Linear Algebra, namely, using the matrices and working on a space that has already basis defined on it. However, I briefly heard in a talk that one does not need a basis to derive the relations we are used to calculate using sums and matrices. (for example, Det is a functional that preserves volume, and all the relations can be deduced from this relation.) Can anyone tell me where can I find a systematic approach to linear algebra in this manner?

Comment: For a first-timer, try Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right". For graduate level, try Hoffman & Kunze, or Bourbaki.

Comment: I'm personally also fond of Winitzki: https://sites.google.com/site/winitzki/linalg